# Using GP_fit() of GPfit package in R

Tags: r, gaussian-process, error-message

I am trying to work with Gaussian process through `GPfit` package of R but every time I use `GP_fit()` of this package, either it gets hanged or throws error which is like this:

```
Error in chol.default(Sig) : 
  the leading minor of order 2 is not positive definite.
```

My input matrix looks like this:

```
     visitLength       hour
   [1,] 0.0241057543 0.73913043
   [2,] 0.0413780103 0.91304348
   [3,] 0.0432866771 0.30434783
   [4,] 0.0000000000 0.17391304
   [5,] 0.0639756822 0.60869565
   [6,] 0.1239219567 0.86956522
   [7,] 0.0000000000 0.34782609
   [8,] 0.0389038126 0.17391304
   [9,] 0.0886469674 0.04347826
     .      .             .
     .      .             .
```

and so on. There are about 200 rows in this input matrix. My output matrix looks like this:

```
     [,1]
   [1,]    0
   [2,]    0
   [3,]    1
   [4,]    0
   [5,]    1
   [6,]    0
   [7,]    0
   [8,]    1
   [9,]    0
```

and this too has same number of rows as the input matrix. Now when I use:

```
model = GP_fit(input_mat,outpt_mat)
```

either it gets hanged or the above mentioned error is thrown. I have no idea why it gets hanged when there are only 2000 rows and also I have scaled values in range [0,1] or it throws as error which does not clarify the meaning or reason. Can anyone provide some information about what and why is it happening?

**UPDATE:** The signature of GP_fit() is:

```
GP_fit(X,Y)
```

where

```
X is the (n x d) design matrix
Y is the (n x 1) vector of simulator outputs.
```

One of the **example code** given **in the package documentation** is like this:

```
 library(GPfit)  
n = 5; d = 1;
    computer_simulator <- function(x){
    x = 2*x+0.5;
    y = sin(10*pi*x)/(2*x) + (x-1)^4;
    return(y)
    }
    set.seed(3);
    library(lhs);
    x = maximinLHS(n,d);
    y = computer_simulator(x);
    GPmodel = GP_fit(x,y);
    print(GPmodel)
```

Comment: I don't know the package you're talking about, but `chol.default` is the Cholesky decomposition function. It seems something about your input array is creating a singular matrix within the code. I would look for `NA` values and/or make sure you are not sending collinear arrays.

Comment: @gmacfarlane I have checked all the values and none of them is `NA`. Also I have added some extra information regarding the function in my post above.

Comment: could the values of only 1 or 0 in Y for me create issues?

Comment: Since `y` isn't even remotely Gaussian, trying to model it as a Gaussian process is inherently hopeless.  What are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have identical rows in you input matrix?

If yes, try to remove them, e.g. by adding a small noise.

Comment: This looks like a genuine effort to help the OP to me, @Andre.  However, it's not likely to be correct: `GP_fit` generally has no problems with repeated rows (nor should it, in theory).